# Awk script in bash script doesn't launch

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

Good day for everyone.

I have a following problem:
In my bash script, I need to execute an awk script (script.awk). I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in apple; do
     source ./script.awk $i.svm > $i.result
done
```

But in this case, I got an error " ./script.awk: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token '(' ; line 3: 'for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {' ", whereas when I execute the script.awk in the command line, it works.

The beginning of the script.awk:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
     for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        split ($i,a,":");
         .....
```

Thanks.

Comment: show a full awk script that displays the problem.

Comment: You cant source an awk script, like you would another bash script. Sourcing is for executing a shell script from within the current shell. This requires that they use the same interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
for i in apple; do
     awk -f ./script.awk $i.svm > $i.result
done
```